# Image doesn't cover all div in Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm codding such grid with pictures in Bootstrap 5 framework.
[image]

My code for this grid:

```css
#project_images img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<section>
            <div class="container" id="project_images">
                <div class="row gy-3 gy-lg-4">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="row gx-3 gy-3 gx-lg-4 gy-lg-4">
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-7"><img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/Geotar_1.jpg"></div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-5"><img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/Geotar_2.jpg"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="row gx-3 gy-3 gx-lg-4">
                            <div class="col"><img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/Geotar_3.jpg"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="row gx-0 gy-3 gy-lg-4">
                                    <div class="col-12"><img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/Geotar_4.jpg"></div>
                                    <div class="col-12"><img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/Geotar_5.jpg"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

All pictures have different sizes. And with CSS rules above they all fit in "div" perfectly, except for bottom right image (name "Geotar_5.jpg"). At the screenshot you can see a little step, because this image haven't 100% height of the "div". And I don't know how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the problem. See the [snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/6p1s04wo/7/).

Comment: @RokBenko, may be because you use same image. I think I found what the problem is. There is something wrong with this particular image (other pictures from grid fits perfectly at this place). I think problem with aspect ratio of the this exact picture.

Comment: Can you upload the image to [Imgur](https://imgur.com/upload)?

Comment: @RokBenko, https://imgur.com/a/NTkWdi9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `d-flex align-items-stretch` Bootstrap classes to the `col-md-4`.

See the snippet below.

```css
#project_images img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <div class="container" id="project_images">
      <div class="row gy-3 gy-lg-4">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="row gx-3 gy-3 gx-lg-4 gy-lg-4">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-7"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/610c4cdf8c386b34153a0a5addc98db1a5129185/0_288_4380_2629/master/4380.jpg?width=1200&height=900&quality=85&auto=format&fit=crop&s=b6094b41c691a8bf00a5f1f689b9e83f"></div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-5"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/610c4cdf8c386b34153a0a5addc98db1a5129185/0_288_4380_2629/master/4380.jpg?width=1200&height=900&quality=85&auto=format&fit=crop&s=b6094b41c691a8bf00a5f1f689b9e83f"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="row gx-3 gy-3 gx-lg-4">
            <div class="col"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/610c4cdf8c386b34153a0a5addc98db1a5129185/0_288_4380_2629/master/4380.jpg?width=1200&height=900&quality=85&auto=format&fit=crop&s=b6094b41c691a8bf00a5f1f689b9e83f"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
              <div class="row gx-0 gy-3 gy-lg-4">
                <div class="col-12"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/610c4cdf8c386b34153a0a5addc98db1a5129185/0_288_4380_2629/master/4380.jpg?width=1200&height=900&quality=85&auto=format&fit=crop&s=b6094b41c691a8bf00a5f1f689b9e83f"></div>
                <div class="col-12"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.imgur.com/K2R24I4.jpeg"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```